# XLConnect setcellformula usage

Tags: excel, xlconnect

I was going through the XLConnect package reference manual. I came across one function called "SetCellFormula" and its example. I was trying to implement this for data in the text file imported into Excel.

What I wish to do is the following
1. Import data of 200 rows and 400 columns into the Excel file.
2. For each row of data containing 400 columns, compute average, median, minimum and maximum and place the results in another sheet. I want to use the SetCellFormula in case I want to edit the cells directly into Excel, as there are associated features like idx2col, col2idx, ecdt. I find that it is easy to do for a single row. Is there any possibility to do that for all rows in a single statement?
3. Please note that the value for rows and columns can vary based on the type of data available.

Please let me know how to proceed with this.